# Is there a way to convert meters to kilometers in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, type-conversion, location, google-geolocation

i am using `geolocator: ^7.3.1 package`  They mentioned a function that calculates the distance between two geographical points , But the result comes in meters by default

How could this be done in Km

```
    getDistance(){
    double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(52.2165157, 6.9437819, 52.3546274, 4.8285838);
    print(distanceInMeters); // result comes in meters by default which is 144851.67191816124 meters
  }
```

How can I get the result in kilometers, and in short number not like that long number in their example?

Comment: use distanceInMeters / 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conversion**

```
  double distanceInMeters = 144851.67191816124;
  double distanceInKiloMeters = distanceInMeters / 1000;
  double roundDistanceInKM =
      double.parse((distanceInKiloMeters).toStringAsFixed(2));

  print(distanceInMeters);
  print(distanceInKiloMeters);
  print(roundDistanceInKM);
```

**Output**

```
144851.67191816124
144.85167191816123
144.85
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: yes !! thanks jmdlb , These calculations are only for the result that I referred to in my question, or for any result? i mean what if the distance was less than 1000 , is still will work as expected ?

Comment: @Moe Hmd

If distanceInMeters = 144 then, { 144.0 | 0.144 | 0.14}